# 2 Unit test controllers to verify that action created new record

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp

How can I assert that a new record was created in my Member's test database when I unit test the Members controller's register action?

I'm trying to use getLastInsertID but I don't know how to load the Member model to make the call.

I already have tests for my Member model which cover register and activate, but there is an error when I go through the activation process.  I would like to use a test in the controller to verify that a new member can be registered and then activated using two tests.

**Update**
I added `App::uses('Member', 'Model');` to my Controller test, and also

```
  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->Member = ClassRegistry::init('Member');
  }
```

in function testRegister I have:

```
   $data = array(
      'Member' => array(
        'first_name' => 'Foo',
        'last_name' => 'Bar',
        'email' => 'foobar@example.org',
        'password' => 'password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'password',
        'security_question' => 0, // Your father's middle name?
        'security_answer' => 'Randolf the great',
      ),
    );
    $result = $this->testAction(
      '/Members/register',
      array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post')
    );
    debug($result);

    $this->assertTrue($this->Member->validationErrors);
    $this->assertTrue($this->Member->getLastInsertId());
```

The assertions show "Failed to assert that array() is true" and "failed to assert that null is true".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find enough information in `$this->vars` to find the record with my Model.  Everything tests out now.